# django Is there a way to get a reversed url without passing parameters?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using ajax data to pass info to my page, but I need to create some links that use data from the javascript to call a view, so the parameters usually passed when one does a `{% url 'jobs:close' foo %}`, for example, are not available at the time the template is rendered, but imported later through an ajax call.  Obviously, this causes errors when the template is rendered.

Is there a way to keep the benefit of having reverse url lookups in such a situation, and dynamically get the URL in the template without passing `foo`, or do I need to hard code the URL in the template and paste the parameter on the end later?

Comment: I typically use an obviously-fake parameter and then swap it out later in the JS; hacky, but works.

Comment: I thought about that.  Like hack off everything after the last `/` and paste on my own code, but it seems, as you said, a bit hacky.  It also kind of ruins the whole keeping code separate from presentation part of things a bit, so I thought there should be a django way to do things.

Comment: Just thinking about it though, there may not be a way, considering that it isn't just a matter of leaving those portions out.  URL patterns can be pretty complex, and it would be nearly impossible to make that work.

Comment: No, through the public API there is no way to get the pattern without passing in suitable parameters. If you want something like this you'll have to dig into the internals of the URL dispatcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it, and looking at comments, I decided on the answer of adding a fake parameter and removing it afterwards.  Since it will be removed when the form is rendered, the parameter doesn't much matter.  I chose `1`.

So, in my template, I put `{% url 'jobs:close' '1' %}`.  Then in my javascript, as I call the form in a modal, I use jquery to find the form.  It makes it easy just to use the same URL again, so here it is:

```
var modal = $("#modal");
var closeUrl =  '{% url 'jobs:close' '1' %}';
closeUrl = closeUrl.substring(0, closeUrl.length - 2) + event.data.id + /;
modal.find("#close-job").attr('action', closeUrl);
```

`event.data.id` is where I am storing the job ID that I really need.

It isn't as slick as I was looking for, but it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting 'foo' in ajax response, get the reverse url in ajax response and replace the DOM where you need the url.